# AngularJS Hidden Field Not Sending Data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having an issue with a hidden field and getting the data into the console from that field. I can see the value of the hidden field is correct when I inspect the code in dev tools. However, on submit, the value is not coming across. The value of the hidden field is a child of a bigger page. Here is the code;

```
.controller('ReviewForm', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){


$scope.form = {

    cat1 : "",
    cat2 : "",
    cat3 : "",
    cat4 : "",
    cat5 : "",
    id: ""
};

$scope.submitForm = function() {


    console.log($scope.form)
}])
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="form.id" ng-value="$parent.$parent.gid[0]['id']">

        {{ $parent.$parent.gid[0]['id'] }} // I see this in the browser, it is correct

// The rest of the form is checkboxes..
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        <input class="input-radio" type="radio" id="control_01" name="cat1" ng-model="form.cat1" ng-value="1">
        <label class="label-radio" for="control_01">
            <h4>Very<br />Different!</h4>
            <p style="margin-top: -10px; color: purple"><i ng-repeat="i in [1]" class="fa fa-star"></i></p>
        </label>
    </div>
```

These checkbox values come over correctly..

When I inspect the code I can see it is rendered correctly..

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="form.id" ng-value="$parent.$parent.gid[0]['id']" 
autocomplete="off" 
class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="ChIJn8ORMaIIwYkRDjaLeuBXyN8"> 
// the value listed is correct.
```

However, when I submit the form.. In the console I see..

```
{cat1: 3, cat2: 3, cat3: 3, cat4: 3, cat5: 3, …}
cat1
: 3 // all of these values are correct?!
cat2
: 3
cat3
: 3
cat4
: 3
cat5
: 3
id
: "" // what gives??
```

I would really appreciate any help. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: which angularjs version you are using?

Comment: 1.6 I believe but I need to double check. I should add, I also tried the old way of just doing value={{ $parent.$parent[0]['id]}}

Comment: Yeah I'm on 1.5.11